# How to implement an animated component with a fixed layout in react native

Tags: react-native

I would like to know how to implement a component that has a fixed layout, but frequently updates its display.

Suppose it is an element that needs to be tied to some in app state like a stop watch timer:
[image: stop watch timer with hundredths of seconds]
<sub>(source: [mzstatic.com](http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/6d/90/6d/6d906de5-bde0-7a95-c9bd-212a698207bd/screen520x924.jpeg))</sub>

If the timer is running then the hundredths of seconds should be ticking on every frame. But in react native my instinct is to make that a `<Text>00:12.36</Text>` element.

Obviously calling `render()` is wrong. Is creating a native module the only option for this? Or is there some mechanism to drive frequent display changes within pure js? Are there best practices in this case?

Comment: Take a look at [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) API.

`Note that Animated is designed to be fully serializable so that animations can be run in a high performance way, independent of the normal JavaScript event loop.`

Answer (score 1):

Checkout setNativeProps it allows directly set text (and other properties of elements). Here're  [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html)

You will be able to set text of `<Text>` component as
`this._textInput.setNativeProps({text: '00:12:36'});`